# Rate of change and kinetics order of reaction question

Tags: kinetics, concentration

The rate of reaction is given by the following equation, where [Ker-S-S-Ker] is just the molecule being broken down and [RSH] is an abbreviation for thioglycolic acid

The thioglycolate is in large excess and so essentially remains unchanged.

[image]

Can somebody explain why the answer is C?

I thought the answer was E (because the rate of change, i.e. the derivative, is equal to the concentration of the reactant itself and so, I thought this signifies a decaying curve?)

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, the only thing you'll need is solving the first order differential equation (but before that, let me define $R_0 := \ce{[RSH]_0}$ and $C :=\ce{[Ker-S-S-Ker]}$.

Now, let's solve it assuming (that's what is given) that $R_0$ can be considered a constant.
Then, we have : $$\frac{\operatorname{d}C}{\operatorname{d}t} = -kR_0C \implies \frac{\operatorname{d}C}{\operatorname{d}t} + kR_0C = 0 \implies C(t) = \exp\left(-\frac{t}{kR_0}\right) + C_0$$ (integration constants can be determined using initial values, I won't be giving further details here on how to solve this...)

Hence, since the concentration of your molecule is an exponential function of time, it is inevitably a convex function (so only curves C and E can work).
Finally, a simple thought on the values of $k$ and $R_0$ show that curve E cannot be the answer as the decay is to "fast".

Hope this helps, if needed I can also provide a "variables separation" method of solving the differential equation.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas Prévost ! You lost me at some parts but I think I get it up to the point where you narrow it down to C and E. Why, however, is E 'too fast' to be logical? I don't understand the reasoning for that...Many thanks!

Comment: Well, as I don't have the whole exercise giving the precise context of the reaction, Isuppose that some information are given, or at least some clues explaining why the decay should be that slow. In fact, the "speed" of decrease is given initially by the value of $-\frac{1}{kR_0}$ (as it is the derivative of $C(t)$ for $t = 0$).